# Порядок доставки сообщений попеременно от различных пользователей

Tags: php, очередь, rabbitmq

Во время реализации тестовоого проекта столкнулся с проблемой:

Как реализовать "честную очередь", если у меня есть, напимер, 2 пользователя с разным количеством задач? Например, у одно пользователя 100 задач, а у второго 30.

Как организовать очередь так, чтобы на выполнение приходили задачи по очереди от каждого пользоватиля, т.е. чтобы очередь выглядела вот так:

> 1,2,1,2,1,2 ...

При этом, количество пользователей было не ограниченым, и если в эту очередь добавить еще одного пользователя, то очередь выглядела бы вот так:

> 1,2,3,1,2,3 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Если ты использовал rabbitmq в тэгах то никак. Очередь (queue) устроена таким образом, что сообщения обрабатываются строго в том порядке, в каком были добавлены - "первый вошёл - первый вышел". В твоём примере у тебя сначала будут обработаны сообщения 1212121212 потом 3333333 или 3223132132313213 как-то так :) если они параллельно продолжат работать вместе. То, о чём ты пишешь - "честная" очередь - это не RabbitMQ, это уже про что-то другое. Пиши свою реализацию, для тестового задания - простейшую.

При использовании RabbitMQ у тебя в идеале есть несколько источников и несколько обработчиков (подписчиков). Источники ничего не знают об обработчиках, и наоборот. Яркий пример - логирование. Множество скриптов закидывают в очередь логи, на другом конце подписчик слушает эту очередь, копит логи по 1000 штук и закидывает в ClickHouse. Ну.. как вариант.

Comment: Вообще использование RabbitMQ не обязательно в проекте, я решил его использовать для некой надежности. В любом случае, а можно ли формировать нужную мне очередь в php, например 1000 задач с нужной мне последовательностью и отправлять в rabbitMQ, а после завершения опять формировать очередь, но не теряется тут смысл от rabbitMQ ?

Comment: @Triumvare я не знаю теряется ли смысл, на мой взгляд, его изначально нет по рэббиту. можешь в определённом порядке пихать в массив (РНР) задачи, потом этот массив отправлять в рэббит (если принципиально именно в рэббит), можешь без рэббита просто эмулировать выполнение

Comment: @Triumvare я писал что в рэббит сообщение обрабатываются ровно в том порядке в каком были добавлены, так что да, если ты их в нужном порядке добавишь, то этот порядок сохранится

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!
И да, если не юзать рэббит, тогда как можно надежно и быстро организовать очереди на php ?